# How to scroll/animate iframe by jQuery. Works in FF, IE, Safari but NOT Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

My simple example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Iframe Scrolling Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function scroll() {
                var iframeDocx = $("#tpTopicContentIframe");
                iframeDocx.contents().find("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 1000);
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="scroll();">Scroll to 1000px</a>
        <div id="tpTopicContentIframeContainer">
            <iframe frameborder="0" id="tpTopicContentIframe" src="docpart.html" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome I get this error:

> JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/DENIS/Projects/Tests/Iframe%20Scrollto/docpart.html from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/DENIS/Projects/Tests/Iframe%20Scrollto/index.html#. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

But it is the same domain. It works for FF, IE, Safari but NOT Chrome.

Why is Chrome so strict? How can I make this work in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are yet to properly deal with the `file://` protocol. As long as the pages come from the same domain, if you access the page over `http` your code will work fine.